# Behavex - Unable to execute a feature file with behavex command

Tags: python-behave

I have installed latest version of behavex package . I am trying to execute a feature file . Getting below error ?  Can any one let me know what arguments we are missing ?
Can we use behavex to execute feature files.

Error :

```
behavex -c config\test.json  features/scripts/Data_services/qual_REST_test_172494_Create_manual_snapshot.feature 

usage: behavex [-h] [-c CONFIG] [-t TAGS] [-o OUTPUT_FOLDER] [-d] [--no-color]
[--color] [-D DEFINE] [--exclude EXCLUDE] [-i INCLUDE]
[--name NAME] [--no-capture] [--capture] [--no-capture-stderr]
[--capture-stderr] [--no-logcapture] [--log-capture] [-ns]
[--stop] [--tags-help]
[--logging-level {CRITICAL,ERROR,WARNING,INFO,DEBUG,NOTSET}]
[--parallel-processes PARALLEL_PROCESSES]
[--parallel-scheme {feature,scenario}]
[-ip [INCLUDE_PATHS [INCLUDE_PATHS ...]]] [-rf RERUN_FAILURES]

behavex: error: unrecognized arguments: features/scripts/Data_services/qual_REST_test_172494_Create_manual_snapshot.feature
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment BehaveX is working with TAGs, not yet with feature files PATH.

Most probably in upcoming versions (current is 1.6.0) it will start providing support on feature files PATH.

In your execution, you should use the "-t TAG" argument.

Comment: Thanks . We are looking forward for support of feature file with full path . We are using this approach in your test automation

Comment: What is the tentative time lines for supporting feature file with full path ??

Comment: Latest Behavex version now supports providing the path to feature files